# Add a fourth 2-column table on a page

Tags: tables, columns

I have the following three 2-column tables on a page, and now I need to change it to a four 2-column table on a page. I tried playing around to add the 4th table with no luck. Is there a way I can add the fourth 2-column table next to the third one?

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm}
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm}
|c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm}
}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
$n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ && $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ && $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
\end{tabular}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple four tabulars can be much easier than building this in a bigger tabular. Tabulars can be horizontally stacked like `minipages` by specifying the `[t]` key to be aligned at their top most rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\ 
  \hline
  $1$ & $w_1 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
  \hline 
  $2$ & $w_2 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill % Second tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Third tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Fourth tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $n$ & $w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad my answer could help!

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you are using this for, as it seems a bit odd. I have here created a command which creates a table, if this is something you will be doing a lot.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
% add a fourth 2-column table in a page - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange
% Url: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327659/add-a-fourth-2-column-table-in-a-page
% Date: fredag 2. september 2016 13.55.41



\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mathTable}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \(#1\) & \(#2 \)\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt]
  \centering
  \mathTable{n}{w_n + \mathcal{O}(5^2)}
  \mathTable{n}{w_n + \mathcal{O}(5^2)}
  \mathTable{n}{w_n + \mathcal{O}(5^2)}
  \mathTable{n}{w_n + \mathcal{O}(5^2)}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the contents of the tables are in math mode, I suggest you use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. This will save you from having to type lots and lots of `$` characters. I'd also get rid of the `@{\hskip 1cm}` spacing directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
$\begin{array}{*{11}{|c}|}
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}\cline{10-11}
n & w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2) && n & w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2) && 
n & w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2) && n & w_n +\mathcal{O}(5^2) \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}\cline{10-11}
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```