# To align numbers and boxes that appear in table column

Tags: tables, align

[image]

I have the following table where the columns consist of numbers and a box symbol. Unfortunately it looks messy because the numbers and boxes aren't aligned. Is there a way to align them. This is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
    |c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm} 
    |c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm} 
    |c|c|c@{\hskip 1cm}
    }
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    $n$ & $w_n \pmod{29}$ && $n$ & $w_n \pmod{29}$ && $n$ & $w_n \pmod{29}$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    1 & 1 $\Box$ && 35 & 16 $\Box$ && 69 & 22 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    2 & 1 $\Box$ && 36 & 18 $\boxtimes$ && 70 & 4 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    3 & 1 $\Box$ && 37 & 5 $\Box$ && 71 & 23 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    4 & 19 $\boxtimes$ && 38 & 10 $\boxtimes$ && 72 & 28 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    5 & 13 $\Box$ && 39 & 20 $\Box$ && 73 & 22 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    6 & 11 $\boxtimes$ && 40 & 28 $\Box$ && 74 & 24 $\Box$ \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}\cline{7-8}
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{$B_n=4w_n^2$} \label{table:Bnwn29} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add `documentclass`, begin and end document, packages and preamble material needed to run your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: where is defined `\swb`?

Comment: and please provide image of table, which you obtain with your code.

Comment: `\swb` is still not defined ...

Comment: Sorry. It turns out I am not suppose to use \swb. I changed it to \Box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

In all your MWE version is not defined nor `\swb` nor `\Box`, so I (re)define  `\swb` as `\square` from `amssymb` package. For aligning I introduce one more column in each, "table" and change columns type:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand\swb{\square}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}
                         |>{\raggedleft $}p{1cm}<{$}@{\,}>{$}p{1cm}<{$}
                         |>{$}c<{$}@{\hskip 1cm}} }
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
n   &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}    
        &&  n   &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n\pmod{29}$} 
            &&  n   &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n\pmod{29}$}              \\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
1   & 1  & \swb         && 35   & 16  & \swb        && 69   & 22  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
2   & 1  & \swb         && 36   & 18  & \boxtimes   && 70   &  4  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
3   & 1  & \swb         && 37   & 5   & \swb        && 71   & 23  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
4   & 19 & \boxtimes    && 38   & 10  & \boxtimes   && 72   & 28  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
5   & 13 & \swb         && 39   & 20  & \swb        && 73   & 22  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
6   & 11 & \boxtimes    && 40   & 28  & \swb        && 74   & 24  & \swb\\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
7   & 15 &              && 41   & 10  & \swb        && 75   & 10  &            \\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\cline{9-11}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$} 
    \label{table:Bnwn29}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is this what you looking for?

**Edit:**
it seems that my answer is close to what you like to obtain :-), so some explanations:

- column type `p{...}` is selected that equal with colummns for numbers and symbols can be obtain
- space between `p{...}` columns in above MWE is left to `@{...}`. Temporary set to `@{\,}`. If you like to have bigger space, than you replace `@{\,}` with `@{\hspace{<length>}`
- maby the natural distance betwee tabule columns is adequate. In this case you only delete `@{\,}` (see table image for this case below)

[image]

and changed table columns options definition:

```
   \begin{tabular}{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}
                         |>{\raggedleft $}p{1cm}<{$} >{$}p{1cm}<{$}
                         |>{$}c<{$}@{\hskip 1cm}} }
```

Addendum:
Let mi show two variant of above table design, which are more according to my taste:

[image]

A MWE for it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand\swb{\square}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}[t]{%
                    |>{$}c<{$}
                    |>{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$}|}
    \hline
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}    \\    
    \hline
1   &   1   & \swb                              \\        
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}\hfil
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}[t]{%
                    |>{$}c<{$}
                    |>{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$}|}
    \hline
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}    \\
    \hline
35   & 16  & \swb                               \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\hfil
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}[t]{%
                    |>{$}c<{$}
                    |>{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$}|}
    \hline
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}    \\
    \hline
69   & 22  & \swb                               \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$} 
    \label{table:Bnwn29}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}[t]{%
                     >{$}c<{$}
                     >{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$}}
    \toprule
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}     \\
    \midrule
1   &   1   & \swb                              \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}\hfil
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}[t]{%
                     >{$}c<{$}
                     >{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$}}
    \toprule
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}     \\
    \midrule
35   & 16  & \swb                               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\hfil
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}[t]{%
                     >{$}c<{$}
                     >{$}R<{$} >{$}L<{$} }
    \toprule
n   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}     \\
    \midrule
69   & 22  & \swb                               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$}
    \label{table:Bnwn29}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd split the table into three top-aligned ones; also makes it easier to restructure the tables if lines are added or the number of tables is changed. But this is a different story ...

Comment: I agree with you, but I already put quit a lot effort to redesign table (introduce new column) ... and to make OP MWE compilable. Maybe latter I will do this too (if someone else will not do this meanwhile :-) )

Comment: @Zarko thank you for your effort. Yes this is what I am looking for, except that it would be great if there's a little gap between the numbers and the box symbol.

Comment: @gernot In a simular but earlier question by the OP, an answer was given which splits the table into 3 tables, so the OP already knows this. Probably not worth redoing it. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327659/add-a-fourth-2-column-table-on-a-page

Comment: @shahrinaismail, see edit of my answer. gap can be simple adjust wit set appropriate value in `@{...}` between `p{...}` columns

Comment: @RunarTrollet Too late, I already did it (edit waiting for review). Anyway, it is for the sake of future visitors. Simple tables should look simple in LaTeX, not frightening.

Comment: @gernot agreed.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. And thank you @Zarko for explaining to me in detail about your MWE. It works!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with `siunitx` and 6 more columns in the table (because of the wide column heads). As I don't know why you use `\captionof{table}` within a table, I restored the normal `\caption`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\myBox{\enspace\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newcommand\Boxt{\enspace\ensuremath{\boxtimes}}
\def\modhead{\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$w_n \pmod{29}$}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering\sisetup{table-format =2.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre = {$\Box $}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{
    |c|cSc|c@{\hskip 1cm}
    |c|cSc|c@{\hskip 1cm}
    |c|cSc|c@{\hskip 1cm}
    }
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    $n$ & \modhead && $n$ & \modhead  && $n$ &  \modhead  \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    1 &  & 1 \myBox & & & 35 & & 16  \myBox   & & & 69 & & 22 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    2 & &  1  \myBox   & & & 36 & & 18 \Boxt & & & 70 & & 4 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    3 & &  1  \myBox  & & & 37 & & 5  \myBox  & & & 71 & & 23 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    4 & &  19\Boxt & & & 38 & & 10 \Boxt  & & & 72 & & 28 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    5 &  & 13  \myBox  & & & 39  & & 20  \myBox  & & & 73 & & 22 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    6 &  & 11 \Boxt  & & & 40 & & 28  \myBox  & & & 74 & & 24 \myBox & \\
    \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}\cline{11-14}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$} \label{table:Bnwn29}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses *three* tables. This simplifies the construction of the table and is much easier to maintain, especially if the data changes and needs rearrangements.

The first column shows the alignment with package `siunitx`, the second column uses a different approach:

- The numbers are aligned by adding an invisible digit for the numbers with one digit. As shorthand the active character `~` is locally redefined.
- The boxes are set with three locally defined macros:

  - `\B`: an empty box
  - `\X`: box with cross
  - `\N`: without box, but with the horizontal space of an box.

  The box symbols can easily be redefined by redefining these macros.
  The example uses `\Square` and `\XBox` of package `wasysym`.
- The number of lines are much reduced and the few remaining horizontal lines
  are set with macros of package `booktabs` to get nicer rules with better vertical spacing.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \newcommand*{\MyTable}[1]{%
      \begin{tabular}{
        S[table-format=2]
        c
      }%
        \toprule
        $n$ & $w_n\pmod{29}$\\
        \midrule
        #1%
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    }
    \def\B{\Square}
    \def\X{\XBox}
    \def\N{\hphantom{\XBox}}
    \def~{\hphantom{0}}

    \MyTable{
       1 & ~1 \B\\
       2 & ~1 \B\\
       3 & ~1 \B\\
       4 & 19 \X\\
       5 & 13 \B\\
       6 & 11 \X\\
       7 & 15 \N\\
       8 & ~9 \B\\
       9 & 13 \B\\
      10 & 18 \N\\
      11 & ~4 \B \\
    }\hfill
    \MyTable{
      35 & 16 \B\\
      36 & 18 \X\\
      37 & ~5 \B\\
      38 & 10 \X\\
      39 & 20 \B\\
      40 & 28 \B\\
      41 & 10 \X\\
      42 & 15 \N\\
      43 & 13 \B\\
      44 & 21 \N\\
      45 & ~1 \B\\
    }\hfill
    \MyTable{
      69 & 22 \B\\
      70 & ~4 \B\\
      71 & 23 \B\\
      72 & 28 \B\\
      73 & 22 \B\\
      74 & 24 \B\\
      75 & 10 \N\\
      76 & ~9 \B\\
      77 & ~5 \B\\
      78 & ~1 \B\\
      79 & 24 \B\\
    }
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]